# Uniqueness of limit in measure and inequality holding after limit in measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I would like to have your opinion about the following proofs:

**Theorem:**

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu$ complete and let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Then

(i) If $f_n \overset{\mu}{\to} f$ and $f_n \overset{\mu}{\to} g$ with $f$ and $g$ measurable, then $f \overset{\text{q.o.}}{=}g$.

(ii) If $f_n \overset{\mu}{\to} f$ with $f$ measurable and there exists $g$ measurable s.t. $f_n \overset{\text{q.o.}}{\le}g \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then also $f \overset{\text{q.o.}}{\le}g$.

**Proof** (Attempt of...)

(i) 
Let
$A_k := \{x \in X : |f-g| \ge 1/k \} \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0 $

Clearly 
$ A:= \{ x \in X : f(x) \ne g(x) \} = \{ x \in X : |f-g|>0\} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}_0} A_k$

Fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ e $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have, by triangular inequality, that
$A_k \subset \{x \in X : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge 1/(2k) \} \cup \{x \in X : |f_n(x)-g(x)| \ge 1/(2k) \} =: A_{f,n,k} \cup A_{g,n,k}$

By definition of convergence in measure we have that $\mu(A_{f,n,k}) \underset{n}{\to} 0 $ and $\mu(A_{g,n,k}) \underset{n}{\to} 0$ and then that $\mu(A_k) =0 \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

But then $\mu(A)=0$ i.e. $f \overset{\text{q.o.}}{=}g$.

(ii)
By contradiction suppose that, with $A:= \{ x \in X: f(x) > g(x) \}$, we have $\mu(A)>0$.

Let $A_k:= \{ x \in X : f(x)-g(x) > 1/k \} \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0 $.

We have that $A:= \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}_0} A_k$.
If $A$ has positive measure then there exists some $\overline{k}$ s.t. $\mu(A_{\overline{k}}) = \delta >0$.
Let $\overline{X}:= \{ x \in X : f_n(x) \le g(x) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, by hypothesis $\mu(X-\overline{X})=0$.

Fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that if $x \in A_{\overline{k}} \cap \overline{X}$ then $-1/\overline{k} > g(x)-f(x) = g(x) -f_n(x) +f_n(x) -f(x) \ge f_n(x)-f(x)$ i.e.

$|f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k}$ for all $x \in A_{\overline{k}} \cap \overline{X}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

In the definition of convergence in measure take $\epsilon = 1/\overline{k}$ and fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$; we have:

$\mu( \{ x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k} \}) = \mu(\{x \in A_{\overline{k}} \cap \overline{X}: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k} \}) + \mu(\{x \in (A_{\overline{k}} \cap \overline{X})^c: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k} \}) \ge \mu(\{x \in A_{\overline{k}} \cap \overline{X}: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k} \}) = \mu(A_{\overline{k}}) = \delta >0$.

But then we have that $\mu( \{ x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k} \})\ge \delta$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and then  $\mu( \{ x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 1/\overline{k} \})$ does not go to zero when $n \to \infty$, i.e. $f_n$ does not tend in measure to $f$ which is the opposite of the hypothesis.

$\square$

Is it correct?

Thank you in advance!